# Flatten nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I am using Underscore and I have an object

```
[{
  name: "aaa",
  date: "2020",
  time: [20, 10, 30],
  meal: ["before", "after", "before"],
  amount: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  name: "bbb",
  date: "2021",
  time: [200, 100, 300],
  meal: ["before", "after", "before"],
  amount: [10, 20, 30]
}]
```

And I want to repeat each item in function with time/meal/amount like this:

```
[{
  name: "aaa",
  date: "2020",
  time: 20,
  meal: "before",
  amount: 1
},{
  name: "aaa",
  date: "2020",
  time: 10,
  meal: "after",
  amount: 2
},{
  name: "aaa",
  date: "2020",
  time: 30,
  meal: "before",
  amount: 3
}, {
  name: "bbb",
  date: "2021",
  time: 200,
  meal: "before",
  amount: 10
},{
  name: "bbb",
  date: "2021",
  time: 100,
  meal: "after",
  amount: 20
},{
  name: "bbb",
  date: "2021",
  time: 300,
  meal: "before",
  amount: 30
}]
```

Then I am gonna group them by time and meal.
I tried many things but I couldn't have the result I wamt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of `time`, `meal` and `amount` are always the same you use could [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create a new object with the same properties and flat these into a new array.

```js
const data=[{name:"aaa",date:"2020",time:[20,10,30],meal:["before","after","before"],amount:[1,2,3]},{name:"bbb",date:"2021",time:[200,100,300],meal:["before","after","before"],amount:[10,20,30]}];

const combos = data.flatMap(({time, meal, amount, ...rest}) => {
  return time.map((num, index) => ({
    ...rest,
    time: num,
    meal: meal[index],
    amount: amount[index],
  }));
});

console.log(combos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: The length of `time`, `meal` and `amount` are always the same

Answer (score 0):

If let's say your array is in variable x you can simply do, without underscore:

```
var y = [];
x.forEach(z => {
  z.meal.forEach((val, index) => {
    y.push({
      name: z.name,
      date: z.date,
      time: z.time[index],
      meal: val,
      amount: z.amount[index]
    });
  });
});
```

`y` will then contain your new array.
If you then want to group by some field, or perform other aggregation, and you know SQL, then a fun way to do it is with [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). Include/require it and then you can just do:

```
alasql('SELECT name, date, time, meal, SUM(amount) FROM ? GROUP BY time, meal',[y]);
```